# open pdf with a url

Tags: html, pdf

new to coding - getting there - please bear with me.

I have links to PDF's but would like to have a pdf opened directly when visiting a url for example :

how can I get http://www.example.com/startlist to automatically open a designated pdf ?

rather than the current http://www.example.com/document.pdf

I have searched but all answers seem to revolve around opening within windows or option to download file.

Thanks in advance
James

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please describe your situation a bit more. What is your server system, how are too files handled etc. Without more information answering would require a lot of guessing.

Comment: Hi, thank you, windows hosting, /startlist is an empty directory (apart from containing the pdf) created purely as an endpoint to view the document, I am happy to use html/php I do not know where to start on this I am afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could embed the PDF document within a `<object>` tag in HTML

```
<object data="/document.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
<p><b>Example fallback content</b>: This browser does not support PDFs. Please download the PDF to view it: <a href="http://www.example.com/document.pdf">Download PDF</a>.</p>
```

Or you could use the `<embed>` approach

```
<embed src="/pdf/sample-3pp.pdf#page=2" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
```

maybe in a `iframe`

```
<iframe src="/document.pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
This browser does not support PDFs. Please download the PDF to view it: <a href="/document.pdf">Download PDF</a>
</iframe>
```

You will need to place any of these tags within the `<Body>` tags of your `HTML` page.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Example PDF Page</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<!- This is a HTML comment, replace me with your embedding choice ->
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

A preferred choice to reach the most users would be using a `object` with a `iframe` fallback

```
<object data="/document.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
    <iframe src="/document.pdf" width="100%" height="100%" style="border: none;">This browser does not support PDFs. Please download the PDF to view it: <a href="/document.pdf">Download PDF</a>
    </iframe>
</object>
```

For a live demonstration and credit you can see it in action at [PDFObject](https://pdfobject.com/static.html)

Comment: Thank you the first solution worked great and opened as required, for a second pdf and url,  is there an option to also offer the file for download rather than view  as soon as  http://www.example.com/startlist2 is visited

Comment: not sure I understand what you mean here but you could add another: `<p><b>Example fallback content</b>: This browser does not support PDFs. Please download the PDF to view it: <a href="http://www.example.com/startlist2/document2.pdf">Download a second PDF</a>.</p>`

Comment: Hi Sorry I wasn't clear enough - just if there was a method for www.example.com/startlist to initiate immediate download of the pdf rather than the open ( I can then select when I code which to use) - thanks